# Fighter Game in Unity3D - Fighter hit opponent [unityscript]

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm making a fighter game in Unity. When I punch I need to find a way for Unity to detect that if I'm hitting the opponent. The problem is that I don't seem to find a way to do so. 
Isn't there a way to make it detect if the meshes are touching each other or maybe some better way.

Do you have any ideas?

Regards,
Robert Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a look at [Physics.SphereCastAll](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCastAll.html). Sphere casting is similar to ray casting. Consider sphere casting a *thick ray cast*. The idea behind this is to cast a sphere from where the punch originates in the direction that the punch is going. If any colliders are returned from the function, then you know that it hit something so you will just have to check that what it hits satisfies the right conditions (i.e. is another player).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try this! One thing, what is the difference between SphereCastAll and SphereCast? Because I only have one opponent and I'm moving on one axis wouldn't SphereCast work as well?

Comment: SphereCast would work if you have your players on layers by themselves. SphereCastAll returns Collider objects based on all GameObjects colliding with the SphereCast whereas SphereCast just returns a boolean value I believe. In your case, you can put player A on Layer A and player B on Layer B (for example). In your SphereCast function, you just have to ignore all other layers besides layer B then. You do this by 1 << layerB where layerB is the actual Layer index. In the layer documentation for LayerMask.NameToLayer (I believe) you will find more information. Let me know for more questions!

Comment: Hello again, thanks for your answer. It is working great to a certain point:) The problem now is that I am using the Mecanim animator. The mecanim animator waits for the "punch" animation to finish playing but in the meantime I can cast a lot of spherecasts because it happens when I press the "punch" button.

Now because the Mecanim is so new I can't find much information for javascript. I'm trying to make a script that says: If I'm in this animation state, cast spherecast.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution is to add mesh collider and kinematic rigidbody to the mesh you're attacking with and use OnCollisionEnter to detect collisions with other rigidbodies.

Comment: Yeeeaah, that crossed my mind but I have Character Controller which has a capsule collider on my character and it seems like can't make that work with mesh collider and/or rigid body

Comment: Could you please provide more details about the situation? Who uses Character Controller, attacker or defender? Do you have a separate gameObject (like a hand or a leg) that you want to detect collisions for?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.. I have one player I'm controlling and the other is supposed to be AI, but haven't gotten that far ahead yet. I guess I only need char controller on my player, it's not separate. Here is a link to the game: http://nemar.tskoli.is/robertsi252/tmf3d/ Use "u" to punch. It's only in testing phase so don't mind all the strangeness:)